# Cannot upload CSV file into SQL Server tool

Tags: sql-server, csv

Here I have tool developed from SQL Server. when I was exporting the data from `.CSV` to tool, it was uploading but when I look into tables I don't see any data.

*Log file from the tool that file uploaded successfully:

[image]

This screenshot is from the database table. The file uploaded, but data in it did not get stored.

[image]

Comment: This tool is a proper tool then :D

Comment: You know we can't see over your shoulder, right? Can you post some of the CSV data in the question (as text, not screen shots)? Can you show us the code that's not working as expected in the question (as text, not screen shots)?

Comment: i don't think you're using the right window. you're editing data. Run: select * from yourshinynewtable in regular sql query window